# If line.startsWith("something") don't write this line nor the next line

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file and edit it.

Let's say I have a file that says:

```
a
b
c
d
```

and I have code saying

```
if inputLine.startsWith("b"){
    looking for code to go in here
}
```

how do I then go about not writing neither b and c into the new file.

so the new file would look like this:

```
a
d
```

I hope that makes senses.

I've tried using `continue`. However, it doesn't write `b` but it still writes `c`.

I am also looking for help with doing the same thing but the other way round, basically saying:

```
if inputLine.startsWith("b"){
    delete a && b
}
```

so I will be left with:

```
c
d
```

Thank you :)

edit:

When trying continue I tried doing this is a while loop like so:

```
if inputLine.startsWith("b"){
    while(inputLine != "d"){
        continue;
}
}
```

Comment: It still writes `c` because you never check for `c`.  I am assuming this is in some sort of loop since you are using continue?  Full code please.

Comment: How are you iterating? `scanner.hasNext()`? if yes, then you could set a flag `boolean lastLineSkipped` which you set in your `if` and then check that in the loop and continue again if it is true: `if(lastLineSkipped) {lastLineSkipped = false; continue; }`

Comment: @jiveturkey Sorry I forgot to mention, check edit please.

Comment: Why `c` also should be skipped? Is it because it is `c` or because it is after `b`?

Comment: @Lino unfortunately this is something that I have taken over from someone else and they didn't use scanner.

Comment: Question-asking tip: even if it us just an example and not a real code don't introduce to your examples problems unrelated to question you are trying to ask about. For instance don't compare strings with `==` or `!=` like you did at `while(inputLine != "d")`. Use equals instead `while(!inputLine.equals("d")){`

Comment: @Pshemo because it is after `b`

Comment: Well as @Lino alludes to, you need to get the next input.  I believe `inputLine` is just a String

Comment: @Pshemo thank you I'll remember for future

Comment: @jiveturkey yes, inputLine, is `BufferedReader.readline()`

Comment: Well, between the `if` and the `while` you need to read it and/or in the `while`

Comment: @jiveturkey reading the line inbetween the `if` and the `while` causes a infinite loop, and reading inside the while loop only reads it till a certain moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean skipnextLine = false;

// Assuming you have some loop that loops through each line
for(...) {
    if(skipnextLine) {
        skipnextLine = false;
        continue; // Ignore current line
    }

    if(inputLine.startsWith("b")) {
        skipnextLine = true; // Skip next line
        continue; // Ignore current line
    }

    // Do here what you want to do with the lines that are not skipped
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this works...
what were doing is were creating an integer to know how many lines to skip, the code is mostly self explainitory

```
int linesToSkip = 0;
if(inputLine.startsWith("b")){
     linesToSkip = 2;
}
if(linesToSkip > 0){
     linesToSkip--;
     continue;
}
//do what you want here with the lines not skipped
```